# Python sklearn scaler

Tags: python

if I define scaler first, then call it, everything works fine:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)
```

but calling

```
X_scaled = StandardScaler.fit_transform(X)
```

returns error:
fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'

Comment: The second example is missing parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing parentheses in the one-lined call:

```
X_scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
```

The function fit_transform expects two parameters self and X. If you use StandardScaler with parentheses the self is provided automatically. Otherwise you must also provide an instance of the StandardScaler as self parameter. Your call passed variable X which was treadted as self and therefore the function still missed X parameter. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to include parentheses in function calls:

```
X_scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
```

This should work properly.